# Weekly sales report

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables InvHeader and InvDetail

InvHeader table has the columns:
InvNo, InvDate

InvDetail table has the columns:
InvNo, ProductNo, QTY, Price

I Would like to generate weekly sales for the period 1/1/2023 to 8/31/2023. The week starts with Sunday. Amount column is calculated Qty*Price.

[image: SQL output]

Thanks

I tried this:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, OH.InvDate), 0) AS WeekDate,
    OD.ProductNo,
    SUM(OD.QTY) AS TotalQty,
    SUM(OD.QTY * OD.UnitPrice) AS TotalAmount
FROM
    InvoiceHeader OH
JOIN
    InvoiceDetail OD ON OH.InvNo = OD.InvNo
WHERE
    OH.InvDate BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-08-31'
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, OH.InvDate), 0),
    OD.ProductNo
ORDER BY
    WeekDate,
    OD.ProductNo;
```

I am getting the output as below:

| Weekdate | ProductNo | TotalQty | TotalAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | orangejuice | 12 | 120 |
| 1/1/2023 | GrapeJuice | 17 | 170 |
| 1/8/2023 | orangejuice | 1 | 10 |
| 1/8/2023 | GrapeJuice | 21 | 210 |
| 1/15/2023 | orangejuice | 5 | 50 |
| 1/16/2023 | GrapeJuice | 58 | 580 |

Comment: Please don't use pictures, but share the DDL en DML scripts so we can reproduce your problem.
You might want to look at PIVOT by the way to solve your problem.

Comment: You are going to likely need a `dynamic PIVOT` or `dynamic crosstab` as it seems you don't always know exactly how many columns you want to output. This type of query is possible but not for the feint of heart. The learning curve is extreme if you are not familiar with the approach.